# Videoconferencing using JMF and RTP transmission

Tags: java, rtp, jmf, transmission, video-conferencing

I am working on a videoconference program using java and JMF. I implemented the two classes AVReceive2 and AVTransmit2 to broadcast live audio and video from the web cam. The text chat works just fine but when I start the video on one client, the other one prints "waiting for RTP to arrive" (which is my output when the receiver client doesn't get anything). So the problem is that the client can't send data to the other one. I have tried the following:
- launching the server and the two clients on the same machines. 
- using two then 3 different machines connected in an ad-hoc network, one is a server and a client the second is only a client. 
-same thing but with 3 different machines 1 server an 2 clients.
- using manual ip address (like 172.168.90.60 for the server, 172.168.90.62 and 172.168.90.64 for the two clients with 255.255.0.0 as subnet mask for all the machines).
same problem in all tries. Here is the AVTransmit2 class if you can suggest something. Thank you.

AVTansmit2

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import javax.media.*;
 import javax.media.protocol.*;
 import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;
 import javax.media.format.*;
 import javax.media.control.TrackControl;
 import javax.media.control.QualityControl;
 import javax.media.rtp.*;
 import javax.media.rtp.rtcp.*;
 import com.sun.media.rtp.*;

 public class AVTransmit2 {

     // Input MediaLocator
     // Can be a file or http or capture source
     private MediaLocator locator;
     private String ipAddress;
     private int portBase;

     private Processor processor = null;
     private RTPManager rtpMgrs[];
     private DataSource dataOutput = null;

     public AVTransmit2(MediaLocator locator,
     String ipAddress,
     String pb,
     Format format) {

  this.locator = locator;
  this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
  Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(pb);
  if (integer != null)
      this.portBase = integer.intValue();
     }

    /**
     * Starts the transmission. Returns null if transmission started ok.
     * Otherwise it returns a string with the reason why the setup failed.
     */
    public synchronized String start() {
 String result;

 // Create a processor for the specified media locator
 // and program it to output JPEG/RTP
 result = createProcessor();
 if (result != null)
     return result;

 // Create an RTP session to transmit the output of the
 // processor to the specified IP address and port no.
 result = createTransmitter();
 if (result != null) {
     processor.close();
     processor = null;
     return result;
 }

 // Start the transmission
 processor.start();

 return null;
    }

    /**
     * Stops the transmission if already started
     */
    public void stop() {
 synchronized (this) {
     if (processor != null) {
  processor.stop();
  processor.close();
  processor = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < rtpMgrs.length; i++) {
      rtpMgrs[i].removeTargets( "Session ended.");
      rtpMgrs[i].dispose();
  }
     }
 }
}

    private String createProcessor() {
 if (locator == null)
     return "Locator is null";

 DataSource ds;
 DataSource clone;

 try {
     ds = javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(locator);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     return "Couldn't create DataSource";
 }

 // Try to create a processor to handle the input media locator
 try {
     processor = javax.media.Manager.createProcessor(ds);
 } catch (NoProcessorException npe) {
     return "Couldn't create processor";
 } catch (IOException ioe) {
     return "IOException creating processor";
 } 

 // Wait for it to configure
 boolean result = waitForState(processor, Processor.Configured);
 if (result == false)
     return "Couldn't configure processor";

 // Get the tracks from the processor
 TrackControl [] tracks = processor.getTrackControls();


 // Do we have atleast one track?
 if (tracks == null || tracks.length < 1)
     return "Couldn't find tracks in processor";

 // Set the output content descriptor to RAW_RTP
 // This will limit the supported formats reported from
 // Track.getSupportedFormats to only valid RTP formats.
 ContentDescriptor cd = new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW_RTP);
 processor.setContentDescriptor(cd);

 Format supported[];
 Format chosen;
 boolean atLeastOneTrack = false;

 // Program the tracks.
 for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
     Format format = tracks[i].getFormat();
     if (tracks[i].isEnabled()) {

  supported = tracks[i].getSupportedFormats();

  // We've set the output content to the RAW_RTP.
  // So all the supported formats should work with RTP.
  // We'll just pick the first one.

  if (supported.length > 0) {
      if (supported[0] instanceof VideoFormat) {
   // For video formats, we should double check the
   // sizes since not all formats work in all sizes.
   chosen = checkForVideoSizes(tracks[i].getFormat(), 
       supported[0]);
      } else
   chosen = supported[0];
      tracks[i].setFormat(chosen);
      System.err.println("Track " + i + " is set to transmit as:");
      System.err.println("  " + chosen);
      atLeastOneTrack = true;
  } else
      tracks[i].setEnabled(false);
     } else
  tracks[i].setEnabled(false);
 }

 if (!atLeastOneTrack)
     return "Couldn't set any of the tracks to a valid RTP format";

 // Realize the processor. This will internally create a flow
 // graph and attempt to create an output datasource for JPEG/RTP
 // audio frames.
  result = waitForState(processor, Controller.Realized);
 if (result == false)
      return "Couldn't realize processor";

 // Set the JPEG quality to .5.
 setJPEGQuality(processor, 0.5f);

 // Get the output data source of the processor
 dataOutput = processor.getDataOutput();

 return null;
    }


    /**
     * Use the RTPManager API to create sessions for each media 
     * track of the processor.
     */
    private String createTransmitter() {

 // Cheated.  Should have checked the type.
 PushBufferDataSource pbds = (PushBufferDataSource)dataOutput;
 PushBufferStream pbss[] = pbds.getStreams();

 rtpMgrs = new RTPManager[pbss.length];
     SessionAddress localAddr, destAddr;
 InetAddress ipAddr;
 SendStream sendStream;
 int port;
 SourceDescription srcDesList[];

 for (int i = 0; i < pbss.length; i++) {
     try {
  rtpMgrs[i] = RTPManager.newInstance();     

  // The local session address will be created on the
  // same port as the the target port. This is necessary
  // if you use AVTransmit2 in conjunction with JMStudio.
  // JMStudio assumes -  in a unicast session - that the
  // transmitter transmits from the same port it is receiving
  // on and sends RTCP Receiver Reports back to this port of
  // the transmitting host.

  port = portBase + 2*i;
  ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);

  localAddr = new SessionAddress( InetAddress.getLocalHost(),
      port);

  destAddr = new SessionAddress( ipAddr, port);

  rtpMgrs[i].initialize( localAddr);



rtpMgrs[i].addTarget( destAddr);




System.err.println( "Created RTP session: " + ipAddress + " " + port);

  sendStream = rtpMgrs[i].createSendStream(dataOutput, i);  
  sendStream.start();
     } catch (Exception  e) {
  return e.getMessage();
     }
 }

 return null;
    }


    /**
     * For JPEG and H263, we know that they only work for particular
     * sizes.  So we'll perform extra checking here to make sure they
     * are of the right sizes.
     */
    Format checkForVideoSizes(Format original, Format supported) {

 int width, height;
 Dimension size = ((VideoFormat)original).getSize();
 Format jpegFmt = new Format(VideoFormat.JPEG_RTP);
 Format h263Fmt = new Format(VideoFormat.H263_RTP);

 if (supported.matches(jpegFmt)) {
     // For JPEG, make sure width and height are divisible by 8.
     width = (size.width % 8 == 0 ? size.width :
    (int)(size.width / 8) * 8);
     height = (size.height % 8 == 0 ? size.height :
    (int)(size.height / 8) * 8);
 } else if (supported.matches(h263Fmt)) {
     // For H.263, we only support some specific sizes.
     if (size.width < 128) {
  width = 128;
  height = 96;
     } else if (size.width < 176) {
  width = 176;
  height = 144;
     } else {
  width = 352;
  height = 288;
     }
 } else {
     // We don't know this particular format.  We'll just
     // leave it alone then.
     return supported;
 }

 return (new VideoFormat(null, 
    new Dimension(width, height), 
    Format.NOT_SPECIFIED,
    null,
    Format.NOT_SPECIFIED)).intersects(supported);
    }


    /**
     * Setting the encoding quality to the specified value on the JPEG encoder.
     * 0.5 is a good default.
     */
    void setJPEGQuality(Player p, float val) {

 Control cs[] = p.getControls();
 QualityControl qc = null;
 VideoFormat jpegFmt = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG);

 // Loop through the controls to find the Quality control for
  // the JPEG encoder.
 for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {

     if (cs[i] instanceof QualityControl &&
  cs[i] instanceof Owned) {
  Object owner = ((Owned)cs[i]).getOwner();

  // Check to see if the owner is a Codec.
  // Then check for the output format.
  if (owner instanceof Codec) {
      Format fmts[] = ((Codec)owner).getSupportedOutputFormats(null);
      for (int j = 0; j < fmts.length; j++) {
   if (fmts[j].matches(jpegFmt)) {
       qc = (QualityControl)cs[i];
           qc.setQuality(val);
       System.err.println("- Setting quality to " + 
     val + " on " + qc);
       break;
   }
      }
  }
  if (qc != null)
      break;
     }
 }
    }


    /****************************************************************
     * Convenience methods to handle processor's state changes.
     ****************************************************************/

    private Integer stateLock = new Integer(0);
    private boolean failed = false;

    Integer getStateLock() {
 return stateLock;
    }

    void setFailed() {
 failed = true;
    }

    private synchronized boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state) {
 p.addControllerListener(new StateListener());
 failed = false;

 // Call the required method on the processor
 if (state == Processor.Configured) {
     p.configure();
 } else if (state == Processor.Realized) {
     p.realize();
 }

 // Wait until we get an event that confirms the
 // success of the method, or a failure event.
 // See StateListener inner class
 while (p.getState() < state && !failed) {
     synchronized (getStateLock()) {
  try {
      getStateLock().wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      return false;
  }
     }
 }

 if (failed)
     return false;
 else
     return true;
    }

    /****************************************************************
     * Inner Classes
     ****************************************************************/

    class StateListener implements ControllerListener {

 public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent ce) {

     // If there was an error during configure or
     // realize, the processor will be closed
     if (ce instanceof ControllerClosedEvent)
  setFailed();

     // All controller events, send a notification
     // to the waiting thread in waitForState method.
     if (ce instanceof ControllerEvent) {
  synchronized (getStateLock()) {
      getStateLock().notifyAll();
  }
     }
 }
    }


    /****************************************************************
     * Sample Usage for AVTransmit2 class
     ****************************************************************/

   /* public static void main(String [] args) {
 // We need three parameters to do the transmission
 // For example,
 //   java AVTransmit2 file:/C:/media/test.mov  129.130.131.132 42050

 if (args.length < 3) {
     prUsage();
 }

 Format fmt = null;
 int i = 0;

 // Create a audio transmit object with the specified params.
 AVTransmit2 at = new AVTransmit2(new MediaLocator(args[i]),
          args[i+1], args[i+2], fmt);
 // Start the transmission
 String result = at.start();

 // result will be non-null if there was an error. The return
 // value is a String describing the possible error. Print it.
 if (result != null) {
     System.err.println("Error : " + result);
     System.exit(0);
 }

 System.err.println("Start transmission for 60 seconds...");

 // Transmit for 60 seconds and then close the processor
 // This is a safeguard when using a capture data source
 // so that the capture device will be properly released
 // before quitting.
 // The right thing to do would be to have a GUI with a
 // "Stop" button that would call stop on AVTransmit2
 try {
     Thread.currentThread().sleep(60000);
 } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
 }

 // Stop the transmission
 at.stop();

 System.err.println("...transmission ended.");

 System.exit(0);
    }


    static void prUsage() {
 System.err.println("Usage: AVTransmit2 <sourceURL> <destIP> <destPortBase>");
 System.err.println("     <sourceURL>: input URL or file name");
 System.err.println("     <destIP>: multicast, broadcast or unicast IP address for the transmission");
 System.err.println("     <destPortBase>: network port numbers for the transmission.");
 System.err.println("                     The first track will use the destPortBase.");
 System.err.println("                     The next track will use destPortBase + 2 and so on.\n");
 System.exit(0);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Is your implementation publicly available? can you share it. Does this have RTCP support too?

Comment: I am sorry my implementation is not available it was a project for a customer. This was a long time ago and as far as I remember It didn't support RTCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, I am using a Mac laptop and JMF doesn't recognize the webcam of the mac, this framework hasn't been updated for 6 years. To transfer sound you have to set the locator this way 
`MediaLocator ml = new MediaLocator("javasound://8000");` as JMF detects only sound at 8000 Hz on mac (don't know for other platforms) finally, to transfert a video file or an audio file it has to respect these [formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) Let me know your opinion if you try this on another operating system.